# onResume fragment method not being called

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have an activity **Activity1** with 2 fragments. Everything's working fine but I have one issue :

when I quit the current activity -**Activity1**- (without calling `finish ()`) and go to another **Activity2**, then I click on the backButton on the last activity I go back to the **Activity1** and this `onResume` method is executed

`onResume` **Activity1** code :

```
@Override
protected void onResume () {
    super.onResume ();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction ().replace (
        R.id.my_frame_container, 
        fragmentFactory.getFragment (Fragment1)
    ).commit ();
}
```

`onResume` **Fragment1** code :

```
@Override
public void onResume () {
    super.onResume ();

    Log.e ("onResume ", " Yes ");
}
```

From the [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle) : the `onResume` method of the fragment is called when the `onResume` method of the activity is too.

However in my case the onResume of the Fragment is not called when I get back to the activity.

Do you have any idea how can I execute fragment code when the `onResume` of the activity is called ? Thank you.

Comment: can you post the code that fragment?

Comment: @André.C.S : it's a dummy code, check my edit.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing, but a Fragment's onResume method is *always* called, before it is displayed.  Is the fragment factory actually returning a fragment?

Comment: The docs do not say that your fragment will be resumed when your activity is. Fragments have their own lifecycle, see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html). Still doesn't answer your question though..

Comment: @G.BlakeMeike : Yes it is. So if I understand well, there is no way to execute the onResume method of the fragment right tmalseed ?

Comment: @Andro-Begg If the fragment is visible, on the screen, then its onResume method has been called.  You can, of course, simply call the onResume method from your code, but that would be a very odd thing to do, because it will *not* run the Fragment through its lifecycle -- or make it visible.

Comment: @G.BlakeMeike : yes, that's my issue, the fragment is not being visible..

Comment: Got it!  I suggest you *not* replace the fragment, in Activity.onResume.  The fragment that was, previously, in R.id.my_frame_container will be put back there.

Comment: haha thanks but it doesn't show the fragment view... I also tried this method http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#onResumeFragments() but gives nothing... It doesn't execute the `onResume` of the fragment at all...

Answer (score 0):

Since `Fragment.onResume` tied to `Activity.onResume` of the containing activity, this method won't get called when we switch between fragments, so you need to call it yourself using `OnBackStackChangedListener` as follow

```
getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new OnBackStackChangedListener() {
    public void onBackStackChanged() {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        if (fm != null) {
            int bseCount = fm.getBackStackEntryCount();
            if (bseCount > 0) {
                Fragment fragment = fm.getFragments().get(bseCount - 1);
                fragment.onResume();
            }
        }
    }
});
```